# How to compare frequency of unigrams with frequencies of bigrams, trigrams, etc?

Tags: python, text, nlp, nltk

I want to build a word cloud containing multiple word structures (not just one word). In any given text we will have bigger frequencies for unigrams than bigrams. Actually, the n-gram **frequency** decreases when **n** increases for the same text.

I want to find a magic number or a method to obtain comparative results between unigrams and bigrams, trigrams, n-grams.

**There is any magic number as a multiplier for n-gram frequency in order to be comparable with a unigram?**

A solution that I have now in mind is to make a top for any n-gram (1, 2, 3, ...) and use the first z positions for any category of n-grams.

Comment: Could you give a little more context on how you want to compare the two? I can think of some measures that would make for some comparison (Information gain, specificity), but most of which need a context.

Comment: A unigram(one world) can have maximum occurrence = the number of words in the text a bigram has maximum occurrence = the number of words in text / 2 and so on... 
Maybe a solution is to multiply the frequency of an n-gram with n-1 in order to obtain comparable results

Answer (score 1):

As you've asked this, there is no simple linear multiplier.  You can make a general estimate by the size of your set of units.  Consider the English alphabet of 26 letters: you have 26 possible unigrams, 26^2 digrams, 26^3 trigrams, ... Simple treatment suggests that you would multiply a digram's frequency by 26 to compare it with unigrams; trigram frequencies would get a 26^2 boost.

I don't know whether that achieves the comparison you want, as the *actual* distribution of n-grams is not according to any mathematically tractable function.  For instance, letter-trigram distribution is a good way to differentiate the language in use: English, French, Spanish, German, Romanian, etc. have readily differential distributions.

Another possibility is to normalize the data: convert each value into a z-score, the amount of standard deviations above/below the mean of the distribution.  The resulting list of z-scores has a mean of 0 and a standev of 1.0

Does either of those get you the results you need?

Comment: My use case is for word cloud so will be with words, not letters but I like the idea of comparing the size of unit sets (for unigrams, bigrams, etc.)

Comment: I expected as much, but the example is easier to show with letters.  Let us know how it works for you.

Comment: There is any formula to calculate the number of n-grams for a specified n and 
a number of all words (assuming each of them are unique)?

Comment: This is basic combinatorics, which you see in my answer.  It's `w^n`, where `w` is the word count.

Comment: I think the formula isn't correct. An n-gram contains just only sequential combinations of n, not any n combinations. Let's take the following example:
all words: (1, 2, 3, 4)
all bigrams: (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)
from your formula results 4^2 = 16 NOT 3 which is the correct result

Comment: Ah -- I thought you were asking about possible n-grams in the language.  Thanks for the clarification.  For a sequence of `k` words, you have `k-n+1` n-grams, one starting at each location until you get near the end.  This does not account for recurring n-grams; subtract 1 for each repeated n-gram.